# facebook graph api - get user details commenting on facebook page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway to get user **contact details** those are **commenting on my Facebook page post** or image...i am using Facebook graph API. Able to get name and unique id of user only. **Using Facebook page web hook** it informs me when anyone comment or like my Facebook page post. If there is any reference or KB, very help full for me.

Comment: No, of course not. That I commented on your post, does not mean I want to share my contact details with you. You can only get anything like that from users that log in to your app and explicitly grant it permission to access such info.

Comment: facebook api  /user  ask only for public profile permission 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user